# Can't solve this differential equation

Tags: differential

I am trying to solve this differential equation:

$$xy'' = y$$

But Iam not going anywhere.

I have tried sumation of series but is there some method involving modified Bessel functions?

Thanks

Comment: My first try would be to "guess" $y(x) = \exp \left( \sqrt x \right)$ and then try to correct this guess.

Comment: Make a change of variable of $x=\sqrt{z}$. A Bessel differential equation will pop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  Multiply by $x$ to get $x^2D_x^2$
$$
0=x^2D_x^2y-xy.
$$

Step 2: Switch to differential operator of the form $xD_x$:
$$
0=[(xD_x)^2-xD_x]y-xy.
$$

Step 3: Recreate a quadratic in front of $y$ by letting $x=cs^2$ noting $xD_x=\frac12sD_s$ (from the power $2$ on $s$):
$$
0=[(\tfrac12sD_s)^2-\tfrac12sD_s]y-cs^2y.
$$

Step 4: Let $c=\frac14$ to agree with the coefficient of $s^2D_s^2$ except for differing sign
$$
0=[\tfrac14(sD_s)^2-\tfrac12sD_s]y-\tfrac14s^2y
=\tfrac14[s^2D_s^2-sD_s-s^2]y.
$$

Step 5: Unfortunately the $sD_s$ has the wrong sign.  To fix this, let $y=sz$ and so
$$
0=[sD_s^2-sD_s-s^2]sz=[s^2D_s^2+sD_s-(s^2+1)]z
$$
and we recognise this as the modified Bessel's differential equation of order $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming $y$ is a function of $x$. Assume $y(x)$ can be written as $x^m$.
Then the differential equation can be written as
$m(m-1)x^{m-2}-x^{m-1}=0$.

Solve it for $m$.
and do not forget to add the arbitrary constants in your solution